# SharePoint 2013: Promoted Links Wrap Tiles

Tags: javascript, css, sharepoint

We have implemented a solution to wrap tiles within promoted links as described in the following article:

[SharePoint 2013: Promoted Links Wrap Tiles](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/19622.sharepoint-2013-promoted-links-wrap-tiles.aspx)

This works well for us however now we want to make use of multiple promoted link lists. On the technet page someone already asks for the same thing that we need however there is no answer yet. I noticed that we get the same web part ID as guy that has the same request, being: WebPartWPQ4.

Going trough the script myself i figured that i need to modify the line that finds the promoted links items:

```
var numberOfPromotedLinks = $('.ms-promlink-body > .ms-tileview-tile-  root').length;
```

I tried to modify it like this:

```
var numberOfPromotedLinks = $('#WebPartWPQ4 > .ms-promlink-body > .ms-tileview-tile-root').length;
```

However that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Click the cogwheel, Edit page
2. Select the Insert Tab
3. Select Web Part
4. In Categories column – Click Media and Content
5. In Parts column – Click Script Editor
6. At right side – Click Add
7. In the “New” Script Editor” Box (probably [2]), click the down arrow that appears on the right corner and click Edit Web Part.
8. Then click the EDIT SNIPPET that appears.
9. Paste the following text into the “Embed” box:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js  "></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

// Update this value to the number of links you want to show per row

var numberOfLinksPerRow = 3;

// local variables

var pre = "<tr><td><div class='ms-promlink-body' id='promlink_row_";
var post = "'></div></td></tr>";
var numberOfLinksInCurrentRow = numberOfLinksPerRow;
var currentRow = 1

// find the number of promoted links we're displaying
var numberOfPromotedLinks = $('.ms-promlink-body > .ms-tileview-tile-root').length;

  // if we have more links then we want in a row, let's continue
  if (numberOfPromotedLinks > numberOfLinksPerRow) {

    // we don't need the header anymore, no cycling through links
    $('.ms-promlink-root > .ms-promlink-header').empty();

    // let's iterate through all the links after the maximum displayed link
    for (i = numberOfLinksPerRow + 1; i <= numberOfPromotedLinks; i++) {

      // if we're reached the maximum number of links to show per row, add a new row
      // this happens the first time, with the values set initially
      if (numberOfLinksInCurrentRow == numberOfLinksPerRow) {

        // i just want the 2nd row to
        currentRow++; 

        // create a new row of links
        $('.ms-promlink-root > table > tbody:last').append(pre + currentRow + post);
        // reset the number of links for the current row
        numberOfLinksInCurrentRow = 0    }    // move the Nth (numberOfLinksPerRow + 1) div to the current table row

    $('.ms-promlink-body > .ms-tileview-tile-root:nth-child(' + (numberOfLinksPerRow + 1) + ')').appendTo($('#promlink_row_' + currentRow));

    // increment the number of links in the current row
    numberOfLinksInCurrentRow++;  }
}
});
</script>
```